# Applying using to a SqlDataReader

Tags: vb.net, using

I just want to verify something.  I believe it is likely that if I apply the using command to a SqlDataReader, that it will both close the data reader and dispose of it.  For example:

```
Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader()
   Dim someInt As Integer = sdr.GetInt32(0)
   'other details and actions
End Using
```

Will that close the sdr SqlDataReader after it exits the **Using** code block. (I believe it will, but just want to verify.)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the reader will be closed when it is disposed. From the [`SqlDataReader.Dispose` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.dispose.aspx):

> Releases the resources used by the
>   DbDataReader and calls Close.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. `Using` calls `IDisposable.Dispose`, and the [MSDN page on SqlDataReader.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.dispose.aspx) says:

> **SqlDataReader.Dispose Method**
>
> Releases the resources used by the DbDataReader and calls Close.